# Subtraction assignment gives 0 and not a negative number

Tags: python

I'm messing around with probability and I'm simulating something where a user can bet `x` amount, if the user loses I want it to drain their overall "`bank`". If they win it adds money.

As you can see in the code when they win the money gets "added" using `+=` but how can I do this so the number becomes a negative when they lose (for example `-=`, that didn't work for me).

Code

```py
import random

def get_possible(x):
    return random.randrange(x)

def loop(possibilities, number, loop, bet):
    success = 0
    fail = 0
    for i in range(loop):
        if get_possible(x=possibilities) == number:
            success += 1
            bet += bet * 8
        else:
            fail += 1
            bet -= bet
    print("Success: " + str(success))
    print("Fail: " + str(fail))
    print("Total earned: " + str(bet))

loop(possibilities=14, number=1, loop=100, bet=100)
```

Here when they lose it says the total earned is `0`, I want it to say `- bet_amount`

Comment: `bet -= bet` will always make `bet` 0

Comment: so how do i make it go negative

Comment: If you bet 100% of the bet then once you lose a single bet, you have nothing left to bet later. i.e. `bet` is 0. After that you can't gain anything (0 * 8 == 0) or lose anything (0 - 0 == 0).

Comment: @fiji Your problem is you are not keeping a tally of how much the person has separate from the bet they made.   if you have their current holdings you can subtract their bet from that and that number (assuming they over bet what they hold the number would go negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce a new variable sum

```
def loop(possibilities, number, loop, bet):
    success = 0
    fail = 0
    sum = 0
    for i in range(loop):
        if get_possible(x=possibilities) == number:
            success += 1
            sum += bet * 8
        else:
            fail += 1
            sum -= bet
    print("Success: " + str(success))
    print("Fail: " + str(fail))
    print("Total earned: " + str(sum))
```

Comment: This works if the `loop` is set to 1, but when I do multiple loops the `total earned` goes back to positive

Comment: I updated the answer. You need to introduce a new variable sum to which you add or subtract the current outcome

Comment: When it's a `fail` it still shows up as a positive number

Comment: Which is valid when he for example wins twice (+1600) and lose six times (-600). It's overall +1000

Comment: But when it loses once it should be `-100`

Answer (score 0):

This ended up fixing my issue by adding a variable `total`

````py
import random

def get_possible(x):
    return random.randrange(x)

def loop(possibilities, number, loop, bet):
    total = 0
    success = 0
    fail = 0
    for i in range(loop):
        if get_possible(x=possibilities) == number:
            success += 1
            total += bet * 8
        else:
            fail = fail + 1
            total -= bet
    print("Success: " + str(success))
    print("Fail: " + str(fail))
    print("Total earned: " + str(total))

loop(possibilities=14, number=6, loop=14, bet=100)```
````

Answer (score -1):

You mentioned that when person losses you want to drawn all it's bank amount,so when person losses amount become 0 using code
bet -= bet.
And from observing above code fragment you can see whenever fragment execute(i.e. when person loss bet)always bet become 0. For clear understanding please post original problem defination.